# How to check if a field has changed when comparing two tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables, with T1 being new data that is plugged in weekly, and T2 being the previous weeks data.
I am trying to compare if a field has been  changed between them, called outcome. 
Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT t1.ID
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2
    On t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t1.Outcome <> t2.Outcome
```

However, whatever version I try, I always seem to pull up errors, and am just wondering the most efficient method to perform this task.
Thanks

Comment: Please give us a little example of data as well as your expected result. Also what are your errors ?

Comment: Hi, my apologies.The error I get is "The specified field '[t2.id]' could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause of your SQL statement". My expected result is to show only the data where the outcome field in t1 does not match the outcome field in t2. E.g. If in t2, the outcome is blank, while in t1, it is successful.

Comment: It looks like your provided sql doesn't match your used one... Try to remove these square brackets here: `[t2.id]`. Or use `[t2].[id]` instead.

Comment: Using [t2].[id] still results in the same error unfortunately.

Comment: Please show your original sql query.

Comment: SELECT [t1].[ID]

FROM [t1]

INNER JOIN [t2]

On [t1].[ID] = [t2].[ID]

 
WHERE [t1].[Outcome] <> [t2].[Outcome]

Comment: Is it a syntax error you are seeing?

Comment: No, the specific error is The specified field '[t2].[id]' could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause of your SQL statement".

Comment: I have a feeling that your actual tables aren't named `t1` and `t2` in the database. The real query would need to be posted for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You state in the comments that the query:

```
SELECT [t1].[ID] 
FROM [t1] INNER JOIN [t2] On [t1].[ID] = [t2].[ID] 
WHERE [t1].[Outcome] <> [t2].[Outcome]
```

Returns the error:

> The specified field '[t2].[id]' could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause of your SQL statement.

This error typically arises when you have a SQL statement referencing a field which is found in multiple tables within the `from` clause, and for which you haven't specified a table qualifier (e.g. `Table.Field`), meaning that it is ambiguous as to which table the field should be sourced from.

However, this isn't the case in the SQL code you have posted, since you are explicitly stating the tables from which each field should be sourced (e.g. `[t2].[ID]` indicates that the field `ID` should be sourced from the table `t2`).

From the above, I could only assume that the SQL statement you have posted differs from that which is run and producing the error.

Certainly, I cannot reproduce this error -

[image]